# Delete row in database using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

Why is it not deleting? When I press delete, I should get the id of the row that I will delete.

View:

```
<?php
foreach ($cust_data as $row) {
    echo '<tr class="even pointer">';
    echo '<td class="a-center ">';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" class="tableflat">';
    echo '</td>';
    echo'<td>' . $row->cust_id . '</td>';
    echo'<td>' . $row->firstname . '</td>';
    echo'<td>' . $row->lastname . '</td>';
    echo'<td>' . $row->email . '</td>';
    echo'<td>' . $row->contact_number . '</td>';
    echo'<td>' . $row->address . '</td>';
    echo'<td>';
    echo '<a href="' . base_url() . 'administrator/delete?id=' . $row->cust_id . '">Delete</a>';
    echo'</td>';
    echo'</tr>';
}
?>
```

Model:

```
public function delete($id) {
    $this->db->delete('customer', array('cust_id' => $id));
}
```

Controller:

```
public function delete() {
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
    $this->admin_model->delete($this->input->get('cust_id'));
    $this->customer();
}
```

Comment: `$this->input->get('cust_id')` should be `$this->input->get('id')` that's why it doesn't get the value because you are retrieving a wrong/unsetted posted data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that you **used** to post the value of `id` in your code:

`echo '<a href="' . base_url() . 'administrator/delete?id=' . $row->cust_id . '">Delete</a>';`

while on your controller you used the `get()` using the name of `cust_id`:

`$this->admin_model->delete($this->input->get('cust_id'));`

you cannot get any value because `cust_id` is not the name of the posted value. so change your `cust_id` to `id` like the example below:

```
public function delete() {
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
    $this->admin_model->delete($this->input->get('id'));
    $this->customer();
}
```

Comment: @leo balino thanks dude i tried to solve it for almost hour. :) but i would ask a stupid question again so it will be cleared in my mind coz im still practicing CI where that get('id') come from? im just confused sorry :)

Comment: @EdgarOng lad it came from your view you declared it on `echo '<a href="' . base_url() . 'administrator/delete?id=' . $row->cust_id . '">Delete</a>';` **administrator/delete?id=**

Comment: @EdgarOng when you click the link the address bar shows `localhost/administrator/delete?id=123` am I right? so the posted data is 123 to get it either `$_GET('id');` or the `$this->input->get('id')`;

Comment: @leobalino thank you so much it helped me a lot. have a good day! :)